# unexpected return value, cannot find symbol, incompatible type

Tags: java

I have three errors popping up I am trying to figure out how to fix

- 1st invalid method declaration; return type required
- 2nd cannot find symbol -- symbol: variable a
- 3rd incompatible types: unexpected return value

```
public class Telephone
{
    String number;
    static int quantity;
    static double total;

    private static makeFullNumber(String telephoneNumber, int areaCode)
    {
        a = areaCode + "-" + telephoneNumber;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: `private static makeFullNumber` does not have a return type (after static). `a` is not declared anywhere in your code.

Comment: @ernest_kThank you found out how to recorrect 
public class Telephone {

private String number;
private static int quantity;
private static double total;

public static String makeFullNumber(String a, int b) {
return (b + "-" + a);
}
}